# Why does my ESP32 keep on reseting after startup?

Tags: c, arduino-ide, esp32

I have wired up my ESP32 and after I power it, it keeps on restarting with the message:

```
rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:812
load:0xffffffff,len:-1
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:812
load:0xffffffff,len:-1
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

I have connected a number of devices with a keypad connected on GPIOs [6, 7, 8, 15, 4, 16, 17, 15] and both RTC and LCD Serial Adapter connected on pins [21, 22]. All devices are powered by the ESP32's 5V pin.

Now, strangely, when resetting, if I press number 1 on the keypad (4x4) or disconnect it, the resetting stops and everything works as expected even after reconnecting it. The same happens with the LCD serial adapter. All other devices do not affect the ESP32.

Any insight as to what may be causing this peculiar behavior will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Your logs seem very similar to what I was getting for over a month. Flashing a non-secure-boot enabled project was ok. But building and flashing the exact same project with secure-boot enabled (under menuconfig) gave me the 'bootloop' with 
"load:0xffffffff,len:-1"

It could be that your bootloader.bin size exceeds the default limit (0x7000). This would cause an overlap in the default offset (0x8000) for partition table.

For my case, my bootloader.bin size was about 0x9000 (did a hexdump).

To overcome this, I changed the partition table offset from 0x8000 to 0x10000 under menuconfig. (This resulted in the offset of the app image to shift from 0x10000 to 0x20000) Then flash accordingly with 'esptool.py write_flash...', or use 'idf.py flash'.

Another way is to reduce the size of the bootloader.bin, perhaps by reducing the verbose output to 'warning' or 'error'

Answer (score 1):

From the ESP32 you can safely pull about 12mA amount of current. You probably have too many devices powered by it's 5V pin. 
Consider using an additional power source. Don't forget to interconnect the GND if do it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to always try is the process of elimination.  Remove one device at a time to see which one attached is causing the problem.

But looking at the data I have is GPIO 6-11 is used by the flash memory.  Might double-check me on that.  I have a doc from Andreas Spiess that has the pinouts of several boards and has those GPIO blocked out as unusable as they are used by the flash memory.